# Different int values or the same? EXC_BAD_ACCESS at NSLog

Tags: objective-c, ios, int, exc-bad-access, nsinteger

I have this code:

```
likeButton.tag = spik._id;
NSLog(@"spik ID=%@   likebtn.tag=%@",spik._id,likeButton.tag);
NSLog(@"%@", likeButton);
```

where `spik._id` is `NSInteger`

And this is the output:

```
2012-03-11 19:35:37.751 KwikSpik[44277:ce03] spik ID=39975   likebtn.tag=39975   
2012-03-11 19:35:37.752 KwikSpik[44277:ce03] <<UIButton: 0xd178b60; frame = (20 12604; 30 30); opaque = NO; tag = 90793136; layer = <CALayer: 0xd1788d0>>
```

You see that `likeButton.tag = 39975` here but when I log the button, its tag is `90793136`.

if I write `NSLog(@"spik ID=%@   likebtn.tag=%d",spik._id,likeButton.tag);`

then I get

`012-03-11 23:27:38.290 KwikSpik[45326:ce03] spik ID=39975   likebtn.tag=87582784`

Are these different presentations of one number or different values? Why are these values different?

Later if I write

```
NSLog(@"tag d %d",sender.tag);
NSLog(@"tag @ %@",sender.tag);
```

where sender is `likeButton` then first `NSLog` outputs `87582784` and second crashes with  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x30...)`

What's happening? Why there're different values in `likeButton.tag` and `spik._id` - or they just look like different?

Why NSLog first time outputted `likeButton.tag` with `%@` and the second time it crashed?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"spik ID=%@ likebtn.tag=%d", spik._id, likeButton.tag);
```

When you log your button, tag is not considered as an int.

Comment: Yes, `tag` is not an object; it's a plain vanilla C integer. (`NSInteger` is a typedef for `int` or `long` depending on architecture.)

Comment: However real value is 39975 (or like this), not like 90793136. I don't need this long strange numbers.

Comment: @Wevah spik._id is NSInteger too. But why they are different in log?

Comment: If it's an NSInteger, then you should be using %ld.

Comment: NSLog("button tag == %d", likeButton.tag);

Comment: And what?Values still different despite `likeButton.tag = spik._id;`

Answer (score 1):

They are being interpreted differently by `NSLog` as you used `%@`. Use `%d` to output as an integer.

```
NSLog(@"spik ID=%d   likebtn.tag=%d", spik._id,likeButton.tag);
```

Comment: If I log by this way, output values still different. Why? I equated variables